# When 0 is multiplied with infinity, what is the result?

Tags: real-numbers

Any number multiplied by $0$ is $0$. Any number multiply by infinity is infinity or indeterminate. $0$ multiplied by infinity is the question. Answer with proof required.

Comment: This problem can be considered using limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the sentence "Any number multiplied by infinity is infinity or indeterminate" which is false.

Multiplication is an operation defined on real numbers. If you have two real numbers, $x$ and $y$, you can calculate $x\cdot y$ which is a real number.

$\infty$ is *not* a real number and you cannot multiply with it.

Comment: What I would say is that you can multiply any non-zero number by infinity and get either infinity or negative infinity as long as it isn't used in any mathematical proof. Because multiplying by infinity is the equivalent of dividing by 0. When you allow things like that in proofs you end up with nonsense like 1 = 0. Multiplying 0 by infinity is the equivalent of 0/0 which is undefined.

Comment: And why is the result of any number not 0.0 multiplied by +/-Inf +/-Inf ?

Comment: @EdisonvonMyosotis Your sentence is nonsensical. What do you mean by "the result of any number"?